# Stop applying force to a sprite

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In my spritekit game I am working on applying a wind like force to my game. I have somehow implemented this a number of ways.

The first way I tried is this  : 
**Attempt one** 
In this code here the sprite is first pushed as it should, however I cant get it too stop.

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

   NSLog(@" %d",_time);
  if (_time == 200 /* | _time==400 */ ) {

  [self startPush];


  }
    -(void)startPush
    {

      SKAction *startPush = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [_player.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(50, 0)];
      }];


      SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:1];
      SKAction *stopPush = [SKAction runBlock:^{

     //   [_player.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(-50, 0)];
        [_player.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];


      }];
      SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[startPush, wait,stopPush]];
      [self runAction:sequence];



    }
```

**Attempt Two** 
I attempted to change my code since i saw this post by LearnCocos2d where he said that AKActions are bad for movements.

[Constant movement in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286610/constant-movement-in-spritekit)

So i tried this

Here also the pushing doesnt stop even if pushOn is set to No.
Would love some help in doing the final tweaks in this.

Thank you

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

   NSLog(@" %d",_time);
  if (_time == 200 /* | _time==400 */ ) {


    windOn=NO;
  }else  if (_time==300)
{
pushOn=NO;
}

  if (pushOn)
  {

      {

        [_player.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0.1, 0)];
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a zero force is equivalent to applying ... nothing. You're basically leaving the body as is with this code:

```
[_player.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(0, 0)];
```

Instead you probably wanted to zero the velocity vector:

```
_player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
```

The difference is that applyForce acts as an "add vector" operation, whereas the line above is a "set vector" operation.

Comment: ah its you! I was also of the mind that if I applied the exact same force the opposite way it would negate the  force being applied on it right now. Also, Is it ok using actions to do such a task?