# How to make an object jump and land on a moving platform

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a jumper iOS game where the 'player' moves on a wave. It should be able to jump and land on the wave. **In the current version it jumps but doesn't move back down.**

It does work when the platform is not moving, but the moving platform is crucial for the app.

Thanks, guys!

**Code**

The platform 'characterBaseline' is moving based on this function

```
wave.bar.position.y = CGFloat(Double(wave.bar.position.y) + createSinWave(angle))

func createSinWave(angle:Double) -> Double {

    var sinWave = sin(angle)

    return sinWave

}
```

The player's jump and moves are based on the following function

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if self.onGround {
        self.velocityY = -14.0
        self.onGround = false
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if self.velocityY < -7.0 {
        self.velocityY = -7.0
    }

}

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    // Character op wave
    self.character.position.y = CGFloat(Double(self.character.position.y) + createSinWave(angle))
    self.characterBaseline = self.character.position.y

    // Jump
    self.velocityY += self.gravity
    self.character.position.y -= velocityY

    if self.character.position.y < self.characterBaseline {
        self.character.position.y = self.characterBaseline
        velocityY = 0.0
        self.onGround = true
    }

    // Golf
    updateWaveBarPosition()

}
```

Comment: Not really sure if this is what you are looking for but see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28030259/2158465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to find out what self.gravity is set to and what velocityY comes out after touchesEnded, that's more than likely the source of your problem

On a side note, any reason why you're not using the built in physics?

It's very easy to create a jumping action with SpriteKit's native physics engine.

You just need to add a physicsbody to each sprite (the player and the platform)

```
self.player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.size)
```

Once this is happening you can just run something like this in touchesBegan:

```
self.player.physicsBody.applyImpulse(0, 100)
```

That'll give your player a boost of 100 (you can tweak this to suit how high you want your player to jump). Gravity will sort the rest out for you.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I'm using 'self.character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody' for collisions and physics. Is that what you mean?

I'll try out the way of jumping you've suggested right now.

Comment: Yeah that should help you out a lot. There's a very detailed tutorial of how to set up all the physics stuff here http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners