# SKSpriteNode follow CGPath plus adding SKAction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a game and I want an enemy to move in a circle but the enemy should have constant movement to the left as well. I have tried to create a circle path  with CGPath and make it follow that path and then added a SKAction with constant left movement. But it seems that the node is just following the CGPath without left movement.

Is there any other way to make this possible?

This is my code at the moment:

```
CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, 0, 0, 80, 0, 2*M_PI, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(circle);

SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circle asOffset:NO orientToPath:NO duration:1.5];

SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];
[enemy runAction:[SKAction moveByX:-1000 y:0 duration:3.0]];
[enemy runAction:forever];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't move the same node with 2 move actions. What you can do is place the node in a container node. Then move the container node left while its child moves in a circle.

Another option is to not use SKActions and use something more dynamic and real-time by computing the centripetal velocity manually and shifting the centripetal point overtime. You can see an example of this in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28845347/2158465).